# about javascript comment specification

Tags: javascript

Like below code, '<!--' immediate codes don't execute.
In case of adding line break after '<!--', execute well.
Is this specification for javascript?

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--document.write("TEST1"); // <- don't execute. In case of adding line break, execute well.
document.write("TEST2");
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you put `<!--` there?

Comment: Use // or /*...**/ this will do your commenting..<!-- used for Html Element tag commenting

Comment: You do know `<!--` is for commenting in HTML, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `<!--` behaves similar to `//`, i.e. it comments out only everything after it on the same line. JS doesn't recognize the closing part of the HTML's comment block (`-->`). Looks like you even know this, since you've commented it out in your snippet.

Originally this commenting method was used to hide a script from browsers, which didn't support JS and `script` tags. Instead they showed the content of `script` tag on a page, and a HTML comment was needed to prevent script text to shown on a page.

Comment: @JohnnyHK As you can see from other answers, you can use more "acceptable" ways to comment your script. You can also accept this answer, if you feel it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the first part "appears" to not get executed, is that `document.write` replaces the entire contents of the document with the string you pass.

As such, you're second call to `document.write` overrides the first.

Additionally to that, the use of SGML comments (`<!--`) in javascript is an old, *old*, **old** school technique, that is no longer necessary for browsers. As others have stated, you can use C-like comments in Javascript - `/* comment */` or `// end-of-line comment`.

Comment: OP's code is executed at parsing time, so `document.write()` is not wiping out anything from the document.

Answer (score 0):

The `<!--` snippet is typically only for HTML code in the modern web. If you place this into a `<script>` section, or any JavaScript section, it may be evaluated as a syntax error. More suitable comment systems for JS are as follows:

```
// one line comment

/* multi
   line
   comment
*/
```

Comment: Wrong, `<!--` is perfectly valid token for commenting also in JS.